# Vertical Tangent line in Explicit Function question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've found that the function

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 + 9}{x}$$

has a vertical tangent at $0$, but I did it by graphing the function and noticing that only around 0 is the slope undefined.  I'm asked to show how I can determine ALL THE POSSIBLE VALUES of $x$ where $f(x)$ has a vertical tangent line.  What is a more mathematically rigorous way to show this rather than just viewing the graph and interpreting?

Since an undefined slope means dividing by $0$, I assume that anywhere the denominator is $0$ is a vertical tangent.  The derivative is

$$f'(x) = 2 - \frac{x^2 + 9}{x^2}$$

and trying to plug in $0$ here also gives UNDEFINED.  Finally, I took the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $0$ and the limit DNE, but I can't figure out how this fact is related to all possible vertical tangents.

Thank you!

Comment: $f(x)$ isn't even defined for $x=0$. Actually, you have a vertical asymptote.

Comment: Oh, so it's not actually a vertical tangent line then? I think that means there aren't any vertical tangent lines, because at x=0 there's only a vertical asymptote.  Right?

Comment: Yes. Btw, though exact, your formula for the derivative is strange; a direct computation should give $1-\dfrac9{x^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the verification.  Let me ask you about how you got the derivative.  When I did it, I did it with the instruction to "find the derivative in the most efficient way possible." So I took the original function, moved the 1/x out so it became a product rule problem then solved it like that.  Did you get your derivative by using the quotient rule?  I'm not sure which is the most efficient way, but the quotient rule is still a little hard for me.

I guess these two different derivatives are actually alternate forms of the same result if you use different methods to calculate?

Comment: Much more simply: splitting the expression in two, as  $x+\dfrac{9}x $.

Comment: OK, just so I'm following you correctly, first, I split the equation into (x^2/x) + (9/x), cancel out the x on the left to be left with only x (derivative of 1).  Then it's a sum problem with (x) and (9/x), and you have to use the quotient rule on the fraction to get -9/x^2, correct?   That's how I replicated your derivative.  Is that what is meant by "direct computation?"  Your way does seem a lot simpler than mine! :-p Thanks for all your help with this, you're my hero.

Comment: No quotient rule (at least in practice): only linearity + every one should know the derivative of $\dfrac1x$ is $-\dfrac1{x^2}$, of $\dfrac1{x^2}$ is $-\dfrac{2}{x^3}$, of  $\dfrac{1}{x^3}$ is  $-\dfrac{3}{x^4}$ &c.